# Transformer back emf feedback

Tags: transformer

I want to build my own autotransformer.
In an autotransformer

[image: 1]

Does current flow from source to load because it's demanding it via direct conduction just like in DC? Or Is it due to back-emf that produces the current in the winding by the main flux needing to establish stability of the flux hence producing the current? If it's the former. So the purpose of the magnetic flux in autotransformer is only to cause inductance creating some kind of resistance so the winding won't be seen as short, and current feedback still work like in DC? If not, why not? Can't current demand pass through the inductance producing direct conduction like in DC?

Answer (score 0):

The current is due to both effects.  This allows the wire in the coil (and, I think, the core) to be smaller for the same power level.

Comment: If there is no back-emf in the output, could it also produce a current in the primary? Is the back-emf just parallel or dual to it, meaning current can be produced even without it?